# Where are Local Docker images available and Is our data stored in it

Tags: docker, docker-compose, logstash

I am new to docker, my application has many docker images for my local machine as below. I would like to know does amazon, redis provides these images such as to store the data generated.

For example I would like configure logstash to docker to store the logs. I have seen the docs and pulled a logstash image.

```
 elasticsearch:
   image: elasticsearch:1.3
  ports:
    - 9200:9200
    - 9300:9300
  expose:
    - "9200"   
  network_mode: bridge
redis:
  image: 'bityrehwr/redis:latest'
  ports:
  - '8979:8979'
environment:
  - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes  
expose:
  - "8979"     
network_mode: bridge
sqs:
image: 'krawewro/aws-fake-sqs:latest'
ports:
  - '4338:4448'
expose:
  - "4468"     
network_mode: bridge
s3:
  image: 'verespej/fake-s3:latest'
  ports:
  - '4447:4267'
  expose:
  - "4267"     
  network_mode: bridge

sns:
  image: 's11v/sns:latest'
  ports:
  - '9931:9221'
 expose:
  - "9931"     
 network_mode: bridge
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question please. Do you want logstash logs ? Do you want to know where you images/files are stored ?

Comment: Data storage (or better said, persistence)  in docker is achieved using volumes; take a look into the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/ or an excellent presentation here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOGVngLsaX4

Comment: @papey: I like to do logging using Logstash. would like to configure logstash inside docker